# Maven on Windows, will Git Bash be enough?

Tags: java, maven-2, maven

From what I am reading, to run [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) on a Windows computer I need to download Cygwin.

Can I get away with [Git Bash](http://ruby.about.com/od/git/ss/git1_5.htm)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maven runs just fine on windows, it is just a batch file that invokes Java.  If you have a JRE/JDK on your machine (with JAVA_HOME correctly configured), you'll be fine.

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need Cygwin. Just a Windows version of NT or above.

From the Maven website:

> On Windows, Windows NT and above or Cygwin is required for the startup scripts.

From [here](http://maven.apache.org/download.html).

Comment: Really, mrblah didn't read the website clearly or do his own homework?